# Replace every Minus to Plus in Expression

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation, symbols

Thought this is a rather simple thing, but I was not able to find a solution.
I have a *polynomial* expression like:

```
 expr1 = a^2 - b + c * d
 expr2 = a - b
 expr3 = -a + b - c
```

and I want to replace every - sign to +:

```
 expr1new = a^2 + b + c * d
 expr2new = a + b
 expr3new = a + b + c
```

The problem is that

```
FullForm[a - b]
(* Plus[a, Times[-1, b]] *)
```

thus I cannot use simple replacement.
Do you know a simple way for that?

**Update**
This example does not work with simple replacements:

```
expr4 = (1 - I) a;
expr4 /. {-1 -> 1}
FullForm[expr4]

(* (1 - I) a
Times[Complex[1, -1], a] *)
```

Comment: Do you really mean `every` minus? So given this input `expr = a - b + Sqrt[-x];` which can be complex depending on x, you want the output to become real (depending on x)? as in `expr = a + b + Sqrt[x];`

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks, i was not careful. I added the example which does not work for me.

Comment: @Nasser: I only use complex multivariable polynomial expressions. (thanks, I added the note).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have found the snags and you're right -- it's a simple matter. You just need the right rules.

For a pure symbolic expression you can use Kuba's suggestion.

```
a^2 - b + c*d /. -1 -> 1
```

> ```
> a^2 + b + c d
> ```

For dealing with complex numbers you can use

```
(1 - b I) a /. x_Complex /; Im[x] < 0 -> Conjugate[x]
```

> ```
> (1 + b I) a
> ```

If your  expressions are more complicated than these, you might need more elaborate rules. But I offer more without knowing what form the more complicated expression take.

Comment: Nice trick, decomposing the complex into Re and Im. This works. And it can be generalized to: `expr = expr /. {x_Complex /; Re[x] < 0 -> -Conjugate[x], Im[x] < 0 -> Conjugate[x], -1 -> 1}` - that seems to work for all cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For most of these cases, judicious use of the *undocumented* function `` Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[] `` works nicely:

```
Replace[{a^2 - b + c d, a - b, -a + b - c}, x_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ :> -x, {-1}]
   {a^2 + b + c d, a + b, a + b + c}
```

It will have trouble with complex numbers, however:

```
(3 - 4 I) (a - b I) E^(I t) /. x_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ :> -x
   (-3 + 4 I) (a - I b) E^(I t)
```

so just use `Conjugate`:

```
(3 - 4 I) (a - b I) E^(I t) /. x_Complex /; Negative[Im[x]] :> Conjugate[x]
   (3 + 4 I) (a + b I) E^(I t)
```

However, none of these can deal with `-3 + 4 I`; thus, a separate rule for real parts is necessary:

```
Replace[-3 + 4 I, {x_Complex /; Negative[Re[x]] :> -I Conjugate[I x]}, {-1}]
   3 + 4 I

Fold[Replace[#, #2, {-1}] &, (-3 - 4 I) (a - b I) Exp[-I t],
     {x_Complex /; Negative[Re[x]] :> -I Conjugate[I x], 
      x_Complex /; Negative[Im[x]] :> Conjugate[x], 
      x_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ :> -x}]
   (3 + 4 I) (a + I b) E^(I t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Allways you can use pattern replace

```
expr1 = a^2 - b + c*d
expr2 = a - b
expr3 = -a + b - c

expr/. Times[-1, x_] :> Times[1, x]

(*
a^2 + b + c * d
a + b
a + b + c
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
PlusToMinus[expr_] := ToExpression[StringReplace[ToString[expr], "+" -> "-"]]
```

Comment: This is quite a clever idea, though I don't think you need the `_Plus` pattern since there are other legal expressions (like `(a + b) (a - b)`) that wouldn't work when you match like this. Just a regular blank `_` pattern should be fine. Also, the question was about replacing minus to plus, not plus to minus. I'm also wondering if there are any situations where this string replacement could produce bad results, but I can't think of any right now.

Comment: What will happen for the following input: `-x 0.0000000000001`?

Comment: @Shadowray maybe just remove the plus pattern, I just put it to look fancy. Then you just get an identity function